# delete row in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am currently trying to delete record in grid view which stored in memory

A bit background, The grid currently populate based on selected file on Asp.net fileUpload control.
So, when the user choose the files from file upload and click Add Files, the the files add to the grid. The files is stored on physical location or database. It currently stored in memory.

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="file_upload" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" maxLength="10" accept="text/plain" Enabled="false"/>


    <asp:GridView ID="GridFiles" runat="server" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" Height="122px" ShowFooter="True" Style="left: 173px; 
                    top: 84px" Width="532px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" OnRowDeleting="GridFiles_RowDeleting">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BorderColor="#FFC0C0" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="White" BorderStyle="Dotted" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <emptydatatemplate>
                           <center> No Files have been selected for upload.</center> 
                    </emptydatatemplate>
            </asp:GridView>

 <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Files" onclick="btnAdd_Click" CssClass="submit"/>


.aspx.cs

 protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataTable dt;
            DataRow dr = null;
            FileInfo fileObj = new FileInfo(file_upload.PostedFile.FileName);
            //string FileName = file_upload.PostedFile.FileName;
            HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];
                string FileName = userPostedFile.FileName;
                try
                {

                    if (GridFiles.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        int count = GridFiles.Rows.Count;
                        dt = new DataTable();
                        DataColumn dcFileName = new DataColumn("File Name", typeof(string));
                        dt.Columns.Add(dcFileName);

                        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
                        {
                            if (GridFiles.Rows[j].Cells[1].Text == FileName)
                            {
                                lblMessage.Text = "File already in the list";
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
                        {
                            dr = dt.NewRow();
                            dr["File Name"] = GridFiles.Rows[k].Cells[1].Text;
                            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }

                        dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["File Name"] = FileName;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        GridFiles.DataSource = dt;
                        GridFiles.DataBind();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dt = new DataTable();

                        DataColumn dcFileName = new DataColumn("File Name", typeof(string));
                        dt.Columns.Add(dcFileName);
                        dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["File Name"] = FileName;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        GridFiles.DataSource = dt;
                        GridFiles.DataBind();
                    }

                }



                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "Error: <br>" + ex.Message;
                }

  protected void GridFiles_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {


            //TODO delete 

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a DataKeyNames value to the gridview and a corresponding column in the datatable holding your info and populate it with some id to identify each row. Then try this code at the click event of a delete button placed at each row

```
GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)((Button)sender).Parent.Parent;
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(grdView.DataKeys[gvRow.RowIndex]["ID"]);

DataTable grdContent = (DataTable)ViewState["grdContent"];

foreach (DataRow dr in grdContent.Rows)
{
    if (dr["ID"].ToString() == ID.ToString())
    {
        grdContent.Rows.Remove(dr);
        grdContent.AcceptChanges();
        break;
    }
}

grdView.DataSource = grdContent;
grdView.DataBind();
```